# MapReduce on graph data - reducer returning incorrect additional data

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm trying to run Hadoop Map Reduce on Stanford snap's web graph dataset. The graph is represented as a text file, with start and end nodes, like so (first few rows) -

```
0   11342
0   824020
0   867923
0   891835
11342   0
11342   27469
11342   38716
11342   309564
11342   322178
11342   387543
824020  0
824020  91807
```

The aim is to build an adjacency list for each node, and compute the length of each adj. list.

The mapper emits pairs of start and end nodes -

```
public static class AdjMapper
       extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text>{
      private Text outVal = new Text();
      private Text outKey = new Text();

      public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
      {
        String inline = value.toString();
        if (!inline.startsWith("#")) {
            String[] inVals = inline.split("\t");
            outKey.set(inVals[0]);
            outVal.set(inVals[1]);
            context.write(outKey, outVal);
        }
      }
  }
```

The reducer produces the adjacency list for each node by building a string (`Text`), which contains each adjacent node (coming in from `Iterable<Text> values`), separated by commas, and creates a count of the list, in the loop.

```
  public static class AdjReducer
      extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text, Text> {
    private Text result = new Text();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values,
                       Context context
                       ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      int cntr = 0;
      String adjlst = "";
      for (Text val : values) {
          adjlst = adjlst+","+val;
          // adjlst.append(",").append(val.toString());
          cntr++;
      }
      // to discard the starting comma
      adjlst = adjlst.substring(1);
      adjlst = adjlst+"#"+cntr;

      result.set(adjlst);
      context.write(key, result);
    }
  }
```

This line is supposed to append the length of each adjacency list, at the end of each row in the result -
`adjlst = adjlst+"#"+cntr;`

However, in the result, even though the correct length is produced and added to the list, there is an additional `#1` added to each node's adjacency list at the very end, like so-

```
0   11342,824020,867923,891835#4#1
1   203402,53051,893884,862566,748615,635575,569212,552600,276233,223236#10#1
10  556796,826668,49988,85506,129774,134964,181848,194746,310676,332640,393685#11#1
1000    890302,902208#2#1
```

I added some print statements and was able to get the logs with `yarn logs`, and here is a snippet from the logs -

```
=====
Counter: 4
Adj List: 579169,724176,185821,463266#4
=====
=====
Counter: 3
Adj List: 384668,278120,666332#3
=====
```

So, the list is being built correctly, and the length is also added at the end. But why/how is the `#1` being added at the end?